# ZXing.Net.Mobile not working in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, zxing

I installed ZXing.Net.Mobile in my Xamarin.Forms project. I have no issue with Android project as I am using
 `MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize (Application);` 
in MainActivity. But in my iOS project I am trying to use   `global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();` which is not accessiblein AppDelegate.cs file. I import following packages :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ZXing.Mobile;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
```

Comment: you need to import ZXing too and your project has to reference zxing.ios --> this is different from the android one!

Comment: zxing doesn't have ios i.e. zxing.ios is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either the wrong library or not all you need. Take a look at this:
[image: References and Imports for mobilebarcodescanning]

After that the initialization is as easy as:

```
 scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
        scanner.BottomText = "Der Barcode wird automatisch gescannt";
        scanner.TopText = "Bringen Sie den Barcode in die Mitte des Bildschirms";
        scanner.CancelButtonText = "Abbrechen";
        scanner.FlashButtonText = "Licht";
```